# Calculate the determinant of the matrix ad hence prove

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes, proof-writing, markov-chains

By computing the determinant of $\lambda I-L$ where $L$ is the Leslie matrix, derive the Euler Lotka equation.

$$L=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} &  b_{2}  & \ldots & b_{w-1} & b_{w}\\
s_{1}  &  0 & \ldots & 0 & 0\\
0  &  s_{2} & \ldots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots &0\\
0  &   0       &\ldots & s_{w-1} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

we know $u_{n+1}=Lu_n$ and  $s_i$ is the probability of surviving from age $i$ to age $i+1$ 
and $b_i$ is the expected number of offspring produced by each individual of age $i$

Solution

Im having difficulty of computing the determinant of general matrix, and there where to go from there? Is the method proof by induction?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the determinant along the first column, you'll find the solution iteratively.

Cheers